# ConsoleWidget.paging option in qtconsole

Tags: jupyter, qtconsole

What does ConsoleWidget.paging option do in Jupyter Qtconsole configuration? The documentation doesn't explain very well what this config option is for.

Answer (score 0):

In the qtconsole, text can be displayed in a pager (for instance the help when you type `object?`). The paging option tells the qtconsole how to display this pager.

If you choose `inline`, it will be displayed like in a usual terminal. If you choose `vsplit`, the console will be splitted vertically and the text will be displayed in the lower half, ...